# C# : How to add data data from a ListView control to a Dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, listview, lambda

The list view is like

[image]

i need to add the data from the `Listview` to a `Dictionary<String,String>`.

Now i'm using `for loop` to do this. Is there any way to do this using `LINQ`.

Finally the Dictionary will contain

```
{"A","1"}
{"B","2"}
{"C","3"}
```

**EDIT** My code :

```
        Dictionary<String, String> Dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            Dic.Add(listView1.Items[i].Text.ToString(), listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text.ToString());
        }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you got so far? It's easier to modify the existing code than to write it from scratch.

Comment: What is the DataSource Of ListView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your sample:

```
Dictionary<String, String> Dic = listView.Items
    .Cast<ListViewItem>()
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Text, x => x.SubItems[0].Text);
```